# Function to find all files in a directory and list their filename, without the path, size and type?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I current have something like

find . -type f -execdir stat --format="Name: %n Size:%s bytes Type:%F" {} +

this does parts of what i want however it displays the full file name including the path which i do not need, is there anyway i could change this or a different function?

Comment: Your question title say that you don't want the size and file type, is that correct?

Comment: I've used your exact command and it doesn't show the path unless you mean `./`. Can you show the exact output that you are getting? Also do you or don't you want the size and type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.

There is currently a `./` at the start of **all** of your filenames. So you need to remove it. To do this you can use `sed`.

`… | sed -r -e 's!^Name: ./!Name: !'`

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for.